# Material-Tabs not shrinking correctly when using flexbox

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, angular-material

In my app, the material tabs don't shrink correctly when the width of the page decreases when using flexbox.

I was able to replicate the issue here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xthdcw

Code:

```css
.panel{
  padding: 24px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.container{
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="panel">
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="FirstLongText"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="SecondLongText"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="ThirdLongText"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
</div>
<div class="panel">
  TestText123
</div>
</div>
```

So shouldn't the material-tab-group shrink when the width of the page decreases and show the navigation arrows in the head-bar? But as you can see the second panel is out of place. So what is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this problem has nothing to do with mat-tabs nor flex. the problem here is the elements with `.panel` class doesn't know how to size themselves. they are in a flex container, but there is no `flex` or `display` attribute set on them as well as any sizing attribute. so they fall back to defaults which in this case `display: block`. since there is no `width` set on those elements they take as much space as they can [as explained here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/#block) and since they are in a flex container with no `flex-direction` set, that also causes default behavior which is `flex-direction: row`. consequently elements with `.panel` class are displayed in a row and each of them take as much width as they can (which causes them to take the width of their contents). that said; in order to make things nice all you need to do is to tell `.panel` elements how to size themselves;

```css
.panel {
  padding: 24px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 20px;
  flex: 0 0 50%; /** required to make sure that elements take 50% width no matter whether they can grow or shrink.*/
  width: 50%; /** we are telling elements to size themselves */
  box-sizing: border-box; /** is required to achieve correct size calculations otherwise all those margins/paddings mess things up */
}
```

here is a working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xthdcw-hp4pdg

another solution would be to set `flex-direction: column` on `.container` because elements in a flex container with column layout take full width of parent by default. in this case `.panel` elements know how to size themselves and everything again work just fine.

here is demo for column layout https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xthdcw-p6ab2w

Comment: Thank you so far, it looks like this is going in the right direction. I left out a few conditions: So what can I do, if I want panel 1 to be as large as possible and panel 2 as small as possible (concerning width of course)?

Comment: for that you need to set `flex: 1` and `min-width: 0` on first panel and `min-width: auto` on second panel. see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247140/why-dont-flex-items-shrink-past-content-size). here is the [updated demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xthdcw-et9yym)

Comment: That was the solution! Thank you very much.